# Optuna training a LightGBM- num of trials exceeded the passed one

Tags: lightgbm, optuna

I am trying to tune an LightGBM model with optuna.
My code is written bellow. n_trials is 20, but in the messages i get bellow it says
"Trial 26 finished with value: 0.020511123098087614 and parameters: {'num_leaves': 134}. Best is trial 12 with value: 0.020511123098087614.". And is still running. Anyone knows why isn't finished yet?

```
study = optuna.create_study(direction = "maximize")
func = lambda trial: objective(trial, train_scaled, train.target_encoded)
study.optimize(func,n_trials=20, n_jobs=-1)
```

Comment: It does look correct. Are the trials suggesting the same solution (`num_leaves`: 134)? Could you please write the version of the packages? And post the rest of the code (at least `objective` of yours, but preferably some reproducible example)?

Comment: Why is on trial 26 since i have place n_trials=20 in study.optimize(func,n_trials=20, n_jobs=-1)?

Comment: did you get any solution for this??